# Warnings and segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is a program to remove particular lines in a file. It copies the lines which are needed and prints it in another file in the same directory. I'm not getting any errors except for warnings such as `incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`. When I run the code I also get the `prtintf` statement but when entered input `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Is it related to the warnings or is it something else ?

code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>


char *name_find(char *buf[], char *name[]) {
    const char *p = NULL;
    size_t len = strlen(name);

    if (len > 0) {
        for (p = buf ; (p = strstr(p, name)) != NULL; p++) {
            if (p == buf || !isalnum((unsigned char)p[-1])) {
                if (!isalnum((unsigned char)p[len]))
                    break;  /* we have a match! */
                p += len;   /* next match is at least len+1 bytes away */ 
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}


int main()
{
    char name[25];
    char buf[100];
        setenv("PFILE","/home/ashwin/Desktop/FILE/",1);
        char ori_path[100],new_path[100];
    if (!getenv("PFILE")){
    }
    else{
       strcpy(ori_path, getenv("PFILE"));
       strcpy(new_path, getenv("PFILE"));
       strcat(ori_path, "shadow");
       strcat(new_path, "shadow1");
       }

    bool success=false;
    printf("Enter the command\n ");
    printf("userdel ");

    FILE *fold = fopen(ori_path, "r"); // old file
    FILE *fnew = fopen(new_path, "w"); // new temp file

    fgets(name,25,stdin);
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
    {
       if(name[i] == '\n')
       {
          name[i] = '\0';
          break;
       }
    }

    while (fgets(buf, 100, fold)) {
    // read lines until error or EOF
        if (!name_find(buf, name)) {
        fprintf(fnew, "%s", buf);
        success=true;
        }

    }

    if(success){
        printf("Success !!!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first things first if you treat compiler warnings as errors you wont regret! trust me. how you doit? by adding these compiler flag to the copilation. use these flags always: -pedantic -Wconversion -Wall
did you check fold and fnew file pointers? perhaps one of them is null! you should always check return value from fopen

Comment: what is input and what is expected output ?

Comment: Look at the parameters of your function, why are they `char *name[]` instead of `char *name`?

Comment: The expected output is first it should print "Success" and second it should copy the required lines to a new file

Comment: How do i exit the code if `name` is not in searching file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *name_find(char *buf[], char *name[])
```

You use `char *buf[]`, which means `buf` is an array of pointers to `char`, not a pointer to `char`. Use `char* buf` instead.  Same goes for `name`.

---

Additionally:

```
    FILE *fold = fopen(ori_path, "r"); // old file
    FILE *fnew = fopen(new_path, "w"); // new temp file
```

You should check if the opening of the streams to the files were successful by checking the returned pointers for a null pointer:

```
    FILE *fold = fopen(ori_path, "r"); // old file
    if(!fold)
    {
        fputs("Error at opening fold!", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fnew = fopen(new_path, "w"); // new temp file
    if(!fnew)
    {
        fputs("Error at opening fnew!", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
```

---

Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>


char *name_find(char *buf, char *name) {
    const char *p = NULL;
    size_t len = strlen(name);

    if (len > 0) {
        for (p = buf ; (p = strstr(p, name)) != NULL; p++) {
            if (p == buf || !isalnum((unsigned char)p[-1])) {
                if (!isalnum((unsigned char)p[len]))
                    break;  /* we have a match! */
                p += len;   /* next match is at least len+1 bytes away */ 
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}


int main (void)
{
    char name[25];
    char buf[100];
        setenv("PFILE","/home/ashwin/Desktop/FILE/",1);
        char ori_path[100],new_path[100];
    if (!getenv("PFILE")){
    }
    else{
       strcpy(ori_path, getenv("PFILE"));
       strcpy(new_path, getenv("PFILE"));
       strcat(ori_path, "shadow");
       strcat(new_path, "shadow1");
       }

    bool success=false;
    printf("Enter the command\n ");
    printf("userdel ");

    FILE *fold = fopen(ori_path, "r"); // old file
    if(!fold)
    {
        fputs("Error at opening fold!", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fnew = fopen(new_path, "w"); // new temp file
    if(!fnew)
    {
        fputs("Error at opening fnew!", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    fgets(name,25,stdin);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
    {
       if(name[i] == '\n')
       {
          name[i] = '\0';
          break;
       }
    }

    while (fgets(buf, 100, fold)) {
    // read lines until error or EOF
        if (!name_find(buf, name)) {
        fprintf(fnew, "%s", buf);
        success=true;
        }

    }

    if(success){
        printf("Success !!!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This removed all warnings but I still get segmentation fault core dumped

Comment: @4shwin_26 When this happens exactly? Do you have any output before?

Comment: Nothing. As soon as I compile no errors. So next I ./a.out. I'm prompted for the input when i press enter segmentation fault core dumped.

Comment: @4shwin_26 I edited my answer. Check if the file openings are successful.

Comment: @4shwin_26 Check if `ori_path` and `new_path` have the correct paths assigned.

Comment: @4shwin_26 BTW, I was wrong with the `const` qualifer to `p` before. I was confused. Sorry. Me fool.